# Is it possible to combine Cloud Computing and MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, cloud

The main bottle neck of a web server locates usually in the database,in my case,MYSQL.

More specifically,fulltext search and master-slave replication.

And sphinx is a probable solution for fulltext-search,so master-slave replication is the

final pain in ass.

Is it possible to boost the performance significantly with the technology of Cloud Coumputing,

for instance,by services offered by Amazon?

Just a wild guess!

**EDIT**:what about MySQL and Google App Engine?

Answer (score 4):

Of course.  [MySQL Enterprise for Amazon EC2](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/ec2.html) is one MySQL package for [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).  See also [Setting Up MySQL on an EC2 AMI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ha-vm-aws-setup.html) and [this tutorial/blog post](http://blog.apokalyptik.com/2006/09/05/mysql-on-amazon-ec2-my-thoughts/).

EDIT: App Engine is higher-level than EC2 and is really designed for [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable)/[GQL](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) only.  However, look at [approcket](http://code.google.com/p/approcket/), which allows replicating between AppEngine and MySQL.

Comment: Great tip!
The sure thing I'm now concerned about is :
Is MySQL Enterprise for Amazon EC2 free?

Comment: No, MySQL Enterprise is not free.  However, I added another link to MySQL documentation, which should apply to the free version.

Comment: I've read those articles finally,but sadly didn't find clues on improving performance on master-slave replication

Comment: GAE is so limited that I've decided to choose AWS.Any way to boost the performance of master-slave replication of MySQL leveraging AWS?

Comment: I would recommend you ask a new question for that, Shore.

Comment: done,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046384/possible-to-boost-the-performance-of-master-slave-replication-of-mysql-leveraging

Answer (score 1):

You may want to be careful with just switching your web app to use an external data base (ie amazon, et.al.), you want to understand where exactly is your bottleneck or you may end up introducing more performance problems... Remember that by going to an external DB, you're introducing more latency into each query compared to a local (box or net) query.

If your problem is performance, try to find out exactly where the problem lies first, and then you may want to explore other options like query optimization, caching, etc.

Comment: However, it is possible to run your entire server on EC2, thus eliminating most of the latency issue.

Comment: I've optimized to my best.But the bottle neck still exists:fulltext search and master-slave replication.

Comment: @Shore: How, exactly, is master-slave replication a bottle neck?  This should be behind the scenes.  Sounds like you are very hardware constrained.

Comment: The slaves become several thousand seconds behind of master frequently.Will cloud help solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, this can be a problem with write-intensive, transaction-intensive apps in MySql due to the single threaded nature of the replication schema. Have you tried a multi master approach to balance the write load and the replication also?

Comment: master-master is even more error-prone,I can't do that kind of risk.

Answer (score 0):

Possible - for sure. See for example, [xeround](http://xeround.com), [rightscale](http://rightscale.com), [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) and [phpfog](http://phpfog.com). There are probably at least a few more with more to come. They come in varying degrees of "freeness" (How's that for a made up word?) too.

The question, it seems to me, will be performance and reliability.

Who knows, localhost may become a thing of the past for development.